# How can I use an ActionListener on a JButton to change the background of a JLabel component inside of a JPanel container?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am working with a JFrame Gui, and I have not found a way to change the background of a JLabel using the event handler actionlistener. The main problem is that I have a JPanel created with 4 JLabels inside. I am unsure why I'm not able to use the JLabel variables that are inside the JPanel container. I've tried creating a field for the JLabel, but it returns null when I try to use the .getBackground() method. I've also tried getting the components of the JPanel using a for loop, and changing the labels through that. So far nothing, hopefully this question makes sense, please help me understand this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnoj5.png
This image shows the refactored method that has my JPanel container with its 4 JLabel components.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7Xs.png
This image shows the actionlistener part of my code.

Comment: 1) Don't link to images of text. Add the text itself. 2) And rather than code snippets.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the feedback, I’ll try to format questions accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you declare a jframe first? Example

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

and then you create a JPanel after that.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

and then add your jlabel and stuff in the jpanel and then that is when you call your jframe.

example

```
frame.add(panel);
```

i have the same project before the only difference about our problem is that I forgot to use the JPanel, but I have a JFrame. Create a JFrame first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I figured out that I had declared my JLabel twice. So I had it declared in the method createMainPanel, and also globally. Once I fixed that everything worked.